# High latency for reaching a docker container after the swarm has been idle for a while

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network, docker-swarm-mode

We have successfully created a docker swarm with several containers and we can say that, in general, it is working fine. We are still developing the first version of our product, so there is nothing deployed on a prod environment yet. Our configuration so far is really simple (docker-compose.yml): one network, one volume, 6 services 1 replica each (with the intention to have more replicas in the future), all services are rest services, only 1 node (with the intention to have more nodes in the future).

The only strange thing we’ve noticed, and that is worrying us, is that after the swarm has been idle for a while (e.g. no incoming request on any container on a dev server) we experience high latency while reaching any of the different services in our swarm and it only happens during the first request on each service. So for example:

> Swarm: Service A, Service B
>
> Idle 30 mins --> no incoming requests for any of the services during 30 mins
>
> Incoming request (non-cacheable request) to Service A --> responds after (aprox) 20 secs
>
> Incoming request (non-cacheable request) to Service A --> responds immediately
>
> ... Further hits to Service A respond immediately
>
> Incoming request (non-cacheable request) to Service B --> responds after (aprox) 20 secs
>
> Incoming request (non-cacheable request) to Service B --> responds immediately
>
> ... Further hits to Service B respond immediately

We entered the containers (execute bash) and noticed that:

1. Ping to other container IPs respond immediately
2. Ping to other container names (dns) has the mentioned delay (high latency)
3. The container name (dns) resolution happens immediately (so it is not latency at dns level)

More details:

- Host OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Docker version: 17.06.0-ce

Anybody has any ideas of what could be going on here?

Comment: Are you using nginx? If so see when exactly does the request hit nginx?

Comment: We are using ngnix (kong to be precise, which uses ngnix) but the problem we are facing is about direct requests from one container to another bypassing ngnix. So it is basically a container to container communication issue.

Comment: I posted an issue on the official docker swarm repo. For all the interested pleople, please check https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35054
Also, if you are facing a similar situation please leave a comment or up-vote the issue. The more comments has the issue the more likely is that we get a response from the team.